# Saving multiple listbox values into mysql vb?

Tags: mysql, vb.net, listbox

I have a problem with saving multiple choices from listbox to one tab in table MySQL with commas or something like this.

my query code is

```
QUERY = "insert into epic_foods.tellimuse_toidud (Toidukoht, Toit, Tyyp, 
Lisad, Ilma, Tellimuse_ID) values ('" & Toidud.cmbToidukoht.Text & "','" & 
Toidud.cmbToit.Text & "','" & Toidud.cmbTyyp.Text & "', '" & 
Toidud.lsbLisad.Text & "','" & Toidud.txtIlma.Text & "','" & 
Toidud.txtID.Text & "')"
```

I am trying to save the Toidud.lsbLisad.Text. This is the listbox

Can you please help me

Comment: what help exactly needed? what's the issue with your current approach?

Comment: right now it only saves one option but not others

Comment: SQL is not supposed to be that convoluted to compose - use SQL Parameters instead of gluing strings together

Comment: Im not that familiar with SQL maybe you can give me a code example?

Comment: It would be hard to find a good db related answer here which **doesnt** show how to use Parameters.  And of course, there's MSDN